# call list of function using list comprehension

Tags: python, list, function, list-comprehension

can I call a list of functions and use list comprehension?

```
def func1():
    return 1

def func2():
    return 2

def func3():
    return 3

fl = [func1, func2, func3]

fl[0]()
fl[1]()
fl[2]()
```

I know I can do

```
for f in fl:
    f()
```

but can I do below ?

```
[f() for f in fl]
```

A additional question for those kind people, if my list of functions is in class, for example

```
class F:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.a, self.b, self.c = 0, 0, 0
        
    def func1(self):
        self.a += 1

    def func2(self):
        self.b += 1

    def func3(self):
        self.c += 1

    fl = [func1, func2, func3]

fobj = F()

for f in fobj.fl:
    f()
```

does it work?

Comment: What is stopping you from trying it in interactive mode?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/release/3.2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Of course you can as Fábio Diniz said :)

However for the class method when used as a callable, an object must be given as an argument:

```
fobj = F()

for f in fobj.fl:
    f(fobj)
```

The object must be given as an argument to the callable because when you look at the definition of the method `def funcX(self):` the method needs one argument **`self`**

Comment: How do I do this if I need to pass arguments to the functions?

Comment: That's an odd approach. I think it'd make more sense to move `fl` into `__init__`, i.e. `self.fl = [self.func1, self.func2, self.func3]`. Then you don't need to pass the instance to `f`. But then, it's not clear what OP's trying to accomplish exactly, so who knows.

Answer (score 31):

```
>>> [f() for f in fl]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Absolutely :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The resultant list will hold the return values of your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can - the functions get called as intended.