# How to make a list of lists and return its values from an tkinter list?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I have a question and i hope you can give me clue. I started with object orianted programming, i watched some tutorials but obviously there is still something missing in my theoretical knowledge.

My problem is:

I want to create  a list of lists and display the single entry's in tkinter's list widget. Then i want to get the lists (in the list) with the index. But i can't come up with the solution.

this is my code so far:

creatin a class:

```
class ListofLists:

def __init__(self):

    self.wholeListofLists = []

def addtolist(self, array):

    self.wholeListofLists.append(array)
```

now i want to write it in the list widget. I tried like this:

```
def addtolist():

    array = [entry1.get(),entry2.get(),entry3.get()]

    List1 = Auftrag()

    List1.addtolist(array)

    listbox.insert(END, "Item" )
```

So far so good now when i want to call the arrays in the object i am stuck. I tried this:

```
def showlistitems():

    List1.alleproben_array[index] ..
```

Of course i can't call the objet i created in addtolist() now in showlistites(). And i can't come up with a way to make it work. I would be very thankfull for a little hint.

greetings

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain items from a list within a list this way:

```
list = [1, 2]
listtwo = [list]
print listtwo[0][1]
```

this will print "2"

Comment: okay thank you! But i still need to know how to i can use the object List1 in that method.

Comment: I think I understand your question now. Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461571/call-list-of-function-using-list-comprehension

Comment: does that mean i have to implement all functions in the classes and not edit the object later?

Comment: Yes i would advise to do that indeed.