# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable 1

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want solve for problem or another method to type this command line

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox

root = Tk()
ent = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
ent.pack()

ent1 = ttk.Entry(root, width=40)
ent1.pack()

bu = ttk.Button(root, text="click")
bu.pack()

i = ent.get()

sentence = i
sentence.replace(" ", "")


def buclick():
    if i == i():
        i()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "There is no product with this name")


bu.config(command=buclick)

print("Product" + "      " + "quantity" + "      " + "Price per one" + "      " + "Total")


class Product:
    index = 0
    item = ''
    quantity = 0
    price_per_once = 0
    total = 0

    def __init__(self, item, quantity, price_per_once, total):
        self.item = item
        self.quantity = quantity
        self.price_per_once = price_per_once
        self.total = total

    def return_information(self):
        return self.item + "          " + str(self.quantity) + "               " + str(
            self.price_per_once) + "             " + str(self.sum)

    def print_information(self):
        print(self.return_information())


def ic5501():
    item = "ic 550"
    result = int(ent1.get())
    quantity = result
    price_per_once = 15
    total = (15 * result)
    ic550 = Product(item, quantity, price_per_once, total)
    ic550.return_information()
    ic550.print_information()


def ic5502():
    item = "ic 5502"
    result = int(ent1.get())
    quantity = result
    price_per_once = 20
    total = (20 * result)
    ic550 = Product(item, quantity, price_per_once, total)
    ic550.return_information()
    ic550.print_information()


root.mainloop()


Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed Rabea Smaha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1549, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ahmed Rabea Smaha/PycharmProjects/untitled/untitled.py", line 22, in buclick
    if i == i():
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: i is a string, what would you be doing when you try to call that string like `i()`?

Comment: I suspect that the intended behavior of `if i == i(): i()` is "if the string `i` has the same name as a function in this program, then call that function". Unfortunately, doing that is more complicated than your current approach.

Comment: yes that i want @Kevin how can i do that with another simple method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the interpretation I gave in my comment is correct, one way to allow the user to call functions you define is to put those functions in a dictionary, keyed by their name. Then you can examine that dict to see if `i` belongs to it, and call the function if appropriate.

```
def buclick():
    i = ent.get()
    if i in user_callable_functions:
        user_callable_functions[i]()
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "There is no product with this name")

#put this just above root.mainloop()
user_callable_functions = {
    "ic5501": ic5501,
    "ic5502": ic5502
}
```

Comment: if. `in` here is doing membership testing. It is semantically distinct from the `in` found in `for` statements.

Comment: thanks for it works with me but if is better than for is a loop the massege will show many times

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given us, it seems that on line 22 where you try `if i == i()` you're trying to check if the variable i corresponds to the return value of the function i(). It seems to me that you don't have a function i() anywhere (and it would be a bad name for a function anyway). Maybe what you're trying to check is `if i == result` where `result` is the variable of ic5501 or ic5502 ? Correct me if I'm wrong.

**EDIT**

Upon checking comments, if you're trying to check whether i is a function name, I'd recommend as a basic start (depending on whether or not this is a big project) creating a list with all the function names and associate them with the function.

`my_functions = [["function_1", function_1], ["function_2", function_2]]`

I'll refer you back to another question where the answer could help you use the above solution.

[call list of function using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461571/call-list-of-function-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: your are not wrong but i will add more items not this two only

Comment: When you say more, do you mean a definite number or you'll be adding more but you don't know how many yet ?