# Apply multiple methods to a single object?

Tags: python

While saving outputs in a data structure to check posteriorly. The methods return strings (parsing or selecting HTML, they don't modify the object).

I've found a "hard-coded" solution by creating a class which is not very motivating for now: [call list of function using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461571/call-list-of-function-using-list-comprehension).

[Maybe another Library for checking libraries would be an extreme. I tried to put a few print in Python source but it didn't obey me. It seems that another instance is running]

I've tried this syntax (not possible):

```
result = [obj.f() for f in [append, attrs]]
```

because `append` and `attrs` aren't static functions by default but 'dotted' as showed above.

The goal is just a simple check of all obj methods.

[edits are highly recommended]

**Update**

> In [122]: getattr? Docstring: getattr(object, name[, default]) ->
>   value
>
> Get a named attribute from an object; getattr(x, 'y') is equivalent to
>   x.y. When a default argument is given, it is returned when the
>   attribute doesn't exist; without it, an exception is raised in that
>   case. Type:      builtin_function_or_method
>   [image]
>   getattr(): attribute name must be string
>   [image]
>   Only `2` works. It is the "result" to get (not hard-coding it)
>   [image]
>   More information for 'model' as an object.

Comment: You could do `result = [f() for f in [obj.append, obj.attrs]]` or `result = [getattr(obj, f)() for f in ["append", "attrs"]]`

Comment: I've tried it, and I updated as a result. It seems that I missed attributes, which I am not figured out yet.

Answer (score 1):

You want either bound methods:

```
result = [f() for f in [obj.append, obj.attrs]]
```

or dynamic attribute lookup via either `getattr`:

```
result = [getattr(obj, m)() for m in ["append", "attrs"]]
```

If you plan to do this for a lot of objects, you might want to use `operator.methodcaller`:

```
methods = [methodcaller(m) for m in ["append", "attrs"]]
results_for_obj_a = [f(obj_a) for f in methods]
results_for_obj_b = [f(obj_b) for f in methods]
# etc.
```

`methodcaller` is a way of abstracting the idea of calling a method away from any particular object.

```
methodcaller(method_name)(obj) == getattr(obj, method_name)()
```

Comment: I wrote a methodcaller like these, but getattr expects strings, and not an 'undefined function name' as I pointed. When I use those functions, the object returns Dict sometimes. 'Object' is a parsed HTML from BeautifulSoup's call of html.parser.